# Adjective that expresses something being of great importance

Tags: single-word-requests

I have already considered the word *transcendent*... I am attempting to express that something is of significantly greater importance than our relatively noteworthy thoughts and feelings.

Comment: Please give us some examples of how you would use it in a sentence.

Comment: Do you mean "relatively ***un***noteworthy thoughts and feelings"?

Comment: This thing is "*of the* ***utmost*** *importance*"

Answer (score 1):

You can use *life-and-death* as an adjective as defined in [Merriam-Webster](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/life%20or%20death):

> ***extremely important*** and serious especially because your survival or
>   life may depend on success
>
> involving or culminating in life or death :  *vitally important* as if
>   involving life or death

Nothing could be more important than our lives.

You can also consider using "*vitally important*" or "*of vital importance*" as [vital](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/vital#vital__2) means:

> involving or culminating in life or death :  ***vitally important*** as if
>   involving life or death

Answer (score 1):

I'll go with **paramount**.

> paramount: more important than anything else. ([**OED**](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/american_english/paramount#Paramount))

Answer (score 0):

I would personally use the word "eclipse" or maybe some variation of exceed. But I am more of a 'poetic' prose writer than naught. Transcends works perfectly in this case, in connotation and denotation.